# GitHub/GitLab REST API - Get branches merged directly into Master

Tags: git, rest, api, github, gitlab

Assume we have branches such as Master, develop, feature1, feature2, feature3, bugfixing1, bugfixing2, etc...

Does GitLab/GitHub provide an API to let us know which branches were merged directly into the Master branch?

Note: We are trying to implement a tool to determine which branches were merged directly into the Master branch. One way to talk with Git is REST API.

Example:

- develop, feature2, bugfixing1 merged into Master brach
- Only develop merged into Master branch
- No branch merged into the master branch

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We saw GitLab support API to get all merge requests for a project. However, we don't see a similar API for GitHub.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-project-merge-requests

curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6888/merge_requests"

https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/Get-all-merge-requests-for-a-project-OR-get-branches-merged/m-p/42869

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Don't use a REST API for this.<sup>1</sup>  Git doesn't have one.  Use `git branch --merged`.  But be aware of what it actually *does*.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you do use one, be aware that it almost certainly just uses `git branch --merged`, or an internal equivalent.  Also, be aware that the REST API on hosting server A is different from the one on hosting server B, which is different from the one on hosting server C.  Hosting server D doesn't have an API for it.  But Git can do it natively, and this will work regardless of your hosting server.

---

#### Long

Branches, in Git, don't exist.

OK, that's obviously not true: they do *exist*.  But in a very important way, they don't *matter*.  Only commits really matter.  Branch names mainly serve to *find* commits.  Merging is done *by* merging commits, even if you use a branch name in the process.  So the trick is to ask the question about *commits* first.  Only later, *after* you have that answer, should you start wondering about branch names.

Because of this, it's in general impossible to say which *branch* was merged.  But it is easy to tell if some particular *commit* is merged.  And, a branch *name*, like `master` or `develop`, *always* identifies exactly one commit.  It's just that the specific commit that `master` identifies *changes* over time.  So does the specific commit that `develop` identifies, and so does the specific commit that `feature2` identifies, and so on.

Pictorially, these things may look like this:

```
       I--J   <-- feature1
      /
...--H   <-- master
      \
       K--L   <-- feature2
```

Here, *neither* `feature1` *nor* `feature2` is merged to `master`.  This is because the commit identified by the name `feature1`, i.e., commit `J`—`J` stands in for its actual hash ID, which is some big ugly string of letters and digits—is not an *ancestor of* commit `H`, which is the commit identified by the name `master`.  However, `master` *is* merged into `feature1`, because commit `H` is an ancestor of commit `J`.  Similarly, `master` is merged into `feature2`.

If we now use:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only feature1
git merge --no-ff feature2
```

on the command line, and everything works, we get a new *merge commit* `M`, so that the name `master` now points to this merge commit:

```
       I--J   <-- feature1
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L   <-- feature2
```

Note how all we did was *add* a commit to the drawing: new commit `M` points back to existing commits `J` and `L`.  The branch name `master` now identifies commit `M`, rather than commit `H`.

Since `J` and `L` are both ancestors of `M`, but `M` is not an ancestor of either, branches `feature1` and `feature2` are now merged into `master`.  Note that at this point, we can *delete* the name `feature1`:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L   <-- feature2
```

Commit `J` is still an ancestor of commit `M`, so the *commit* is merged.  But branch `feature1` no longer exists.  It doesn't matter for *using* Git, but now, the list of branch *names* that identify commits that are ancestors of `M` no longer includes `feature1`.  We can do the same with `feature2`:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L
```

We can now create a *new* branch name, such as `feature/short`, that points to commit `J`:

```
       I--J   <-- feature/short
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L
```

Commit `J` is still an ancestor of commit `M`, so branch `feature/short` is merged to branch `master`.

Git itself—not GitHub and not GitLab, just plain old Git—can tell you which branch names point to commits that are ancestors of some other branch name:

```
git branch --merged master
```

first finds commit `M`, then loops through all branch names—in this case, `feature/short` is the only other branch name left—to see if the commit that *those* branch names identify is an ancestor of commit `M`.  At the moment, that is true of `feature/short`, so `git branch --merged` will list `feature/short`.

If we `git checkout feature/short` and put a new commit on it, though, we get this:

```
       I--J---N   <-- feature/short
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L
```

Commit `N` is *not* an ancestor of commit `M`, so branch `feature/short` is *not* merged to branch `master`.  Running `git branch --merged master` will no longer list `feature/short`.

#### Remote-tracking names

To do this from your own Git repository, rather than from some hosting-service API, you will need a clone of the Git repository from the hosting-service.  When you make such a clone, unless you use `--mirror`,<sup>2</sup> your Git will *rename* **their** branches.  You will have, instead of branch names, a series of *remote-tracking names*, of the form `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, `origin/feature1`, and so on.

After copying their commits to your repository and renaming their branch names to your remote-tracking names, your own Git will create one branch name in *your* repository, pointing to one of the existing commits you got from them.  By default, your Git will create your `master` pointing to the same commit as their `origin/master`.  However, over time, *their* branch names will change: they will point to newer, better-to-use commits.  You will need to run:

```
git fetch
```

or:

```
git fetch --prune
```

to get your Git to pick up their new commits and update your remote-tracking names.  Using `--prune` will make sure that your Git *removes* old, stale remote-tracking names: for instance, after their Git has deleted their `feature/short`, your Git will continue to have `origin/feature/short` until you do a fetch with pruning turned on.  Your Git will then notice that they *don't* have `feature/short` and remove your `origin/feature/short`.

What you'll want to do here is use:

```
git branch --merged -r origin/master
```

The `-r` option tells `git branch` to look at your *remote-tracking names* rather than your *branch* names.  The `origin/master` tells your Git to use the commit that your `origin/master`—their `master` as of your last fetched update—identifies.  So now you'll get a list like `origin/feature1` and `origin/master` as remote-tracking names that point to commits that are ancestors of the commit to which your `origin/master` points.

---

<sup>2</sup>It's unlikely that you want to use `--mirror`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, we are trying to implement a tool to determine which branches were merged directly into the Master branch. One way to talk with Git through REST API. That why my question related to Git REST API. Do you think REST API supports this feature?

Comment: GitHub document their REST API: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: BTW I did a quick scan of the GitHub API docs, and unless I missed something (definitely possible—it was a *quick* scan) you'd have to re-implement `git branch --merged` using the clumsy and very slow method of retrieving the commit graph via the API after retrieving the branch references via the API.